# How to generate this responsive layout using tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, grid, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a complex layout using Tailwind CSS, but I'm encountering challenges ensuring responsiveness across different screen sizes. To illustrate my issue, I've put together a simplified representation of my layout using color blocks and numbers.

I want the grid spaces to be fluid in width until the md breakpoint `768px`. Below I've created the just the div/numbers and color blocks to get started.

[image: Desktop]

Note: that on Mobile that section #3 is missing

[image: Mobile]

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<div class="h-full bg-black text-center">
  <div class="bg-rose-600 text-white">1</div>
  <div class="bg-orange-600 text-white">2</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-600 text-white">3</div>
  <div class="bg-green-600 text-white">4</div>
  <div class="bg-purple-600 text-white">5</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-600 text-white">6</div>
  <div class="bg-indigo-700 text-white">7</div>
</div>
```

If you want to know what the final layout looks like perhaps it will help the layout as there could be alternatives to my color blocking example:

[image: MObile Real]
[image: Desktop Real]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider [defining explicit named grid template areas for the content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template). This allows you to control the children without using column/row numbers that could get unwieldy.

You could consider using an [arbitrary property class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties) to apply the necessary properties like:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="grid h-full bg-black text-center [grid-template:'a_a'2fr'e_e'1fr'd_d'4fr'b_f'2fr/1fr_2fr] md:[grid-template:'a_d_e'1fr'b_d_e'5fr'b_d_f'1fr'c_d_f'1fr/1fr_1fr_1fr]">
  <div class="[grid-area:a] bg-rose-600 text-white">1</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:b] bg-orange-600 text-white">2</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:c] hidden bg-yellow-600 text-white md:block">3</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:d] bg-green-600 text-white">4</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:e] bg-purple-600 text-white">5</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:f] bg-blue-600 text-white">6</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:a] self-start justify-self-end bg-indigo-700 text-white md:[grid-area:f] md:place-self-end">7</div>
</div>
```

You could also use "vanilla" CSS for defining the grid layout:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer utilities {
  .grid-stack {
    grid-template:
      "a a" 2fr
      "e e" 1fr
      "d d" 4fr
      "b f" 2fr
      / 1fr 2fr
  }
  .grid-full {
    grid-template:
      "a d e" 1fr
      "b d e" 5fr
      "b d f" 1fr
      "c d f" 1fr
      / 1fr 1fr 1fr
  }
  
  .area-a {
    grid-area: a;
  }
  .area-b {
    grid-area: b;
  }
  .area-c {
    grid-area: c;
  }
  .area-d {
    grid-area: d;
  }
  .area-e {
    grid-area: e;
  }
  .area-f {
    grid-area: f;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="grid h-full bg-black text-center grid-stack md:grid-full">
  <div class="area-a bg-rose-600 text-white">1</div>
  <div class="area-b bg-orange-600 text-white">2</div>
  <div class="area-c hidden bg-yellow-600 text-white md:block">3</div>
  <div class="area-d bg-green-600 text-white">4</div>
  <div class="area-e bg-purple-600 text-white">5</div>
  <div class="area-f bg-blue-600 text-white">6</div>
  <div class="area-a self-start justify-self-end bg-indigo-700 text-white md:area-f md:place-self-end">7</div>
</div>
```

You could mix and match arbitrary properties with vanilla CSS, for example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer utilities {
  .grid-stack {
    grid-template:
      "a a" 2fr
      "e e" 1fr
      "d d" 4fr
      "b f" 2fr
      / 1fr 2fr
  }
  .grid-full {
    grid-template:
      "a d e" 1fr
      "b d e" 5fr
      "b d f" 1fr
      "c d f" 1fr
      / 1fr 1fr 1fr
  }
}
</style>

<div class="grid h-full bg-black text-center grid-stack md:grid-full">
  <div class="[grid-area:a] bg-rose-600 text-white">1</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:b] bg-orange-600 text-white">2</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:c] hidden bg-yellow-600 text-white md:block">3</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:d] bg-green-600 text-white">4</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:e] bg-purple-600 text-white">5</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:f] bg-blue-600 text-white">6</div>
  <div class="[grid-area:a] self-start justify-self-end bg-indigo-700 text-white md:[grid-area:f] md:place-self-end">7</div>
</div>
```

You could also use Tailwind plugins to produce the required CSS:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    gridTemplate: {
      stack: {
        rows: [
          '"a a" 2fr',
          '"e e" 1fr',
          '"d d" 4fr',
          '"b f" 2fr',
        ],
        columns: '1fr 2fr',
      },
      full: {
        rows: [
          '"a d e" 1fr',
          '"b d e" 5fr',
          '"b d f" 1fr',
          '"c d f" 1fr',
        ],
        columns: '1fr 1fr 1fr',
      },
    },
    gridArea: {
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
      c: 'c',
      d: 'd',
      e: 'e',
      f: 'f',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ matchUtilities, theme }) => {
      matchUtilities(
        {
          'grid-template': value => ({
            gridTemplate: `${value.rows.join('')}/${value.columns}`,
          }),
        },
        { values: theme('gridTemplate') }
      );
      matchUtilities(
        {
          area: value => ({
            gridArea: value,
          })
        },
        { values: theme('gridArea') }
      );
    }),
  ],
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="grid h-full bg-black text-center grid-template-stack md:grid-template-full">
  <div class="area-a bg-rose-600 text-white">1</div>
  <div class="area-b bg-orange-600 text-white">2</div>
  <div class="area-c hidden bg-yellow-600 text-white md:block">3</div>
  <div class="area-d bg-green-600 text-white">4</div>
  <div class="area-e bg-purple-600 text-white">5</div>
  <div class="area-f bg-blue-600 text-white">6</div>
  <div class="area-a self-start justify-self-end bg-indigo-700 text-white md:area-f md:place-self-end">7</div>
</div>
```

And of course, you can mix and match all the above techniques however you like.